# Two semi-continuous functions whose sum is nowhere semi-continuous

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, semicontinuous-functions

Prove or disprove the following statement:

There exist functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ such that:
(1) $f,g$ are semi-continuous, i.e. for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is either upper semi-continuous at $x$ or lower semi-continuous at $x$.
(2) $f+g$ is nowhere semi-continuous, i.e. for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f$ is neither upper semi-continuous at $x$ nor lower semi-continuous at $x$.

I read a result on a book constructing three semi-continuous functions whose sum is nowhere semi-continuous. This lead me to start thinking whether two functions would be enough, but I'm getting nowhere with it. Any thought would be helpful.

Here is the three-function construction from the book I was reading:
$$f_{1}(x) = \begin{cases}
 \frac{4}{2q+1} & \text{ if } x=\frac{p}{2q+1}; \\ 
 -2-\frac{4}{2q}& \text{ if } x=\frac{p}{2q}; \\ 
 -2             & \text{ if } x \text{ is irrational}. 
\end{cases}$$
$$f_{2}(x) = \begin{cases}
 -1-\frac{1}{2q+1} & \text{ if } x=\frac{p}{2q+1}; \\ 
 1+\frac{1}{2q}& \text{ if } x=\frac{p}{2q}; \\ 
 -1             & \text{ if } x \text{ is irrational}. 
\end{cases}$$
$$f_{3}(x) = \begin{cases}
 -1-\frac{1}{2q+1} & \text{ if } x=\frac{p}{2q+1}; \\ 
 3+\frac{1}{2q}& \text{ if } x=\frac{p}{2q}; \\ 
 3             & \text{ if } x \text{ is irrational}. 
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Can you please give reference for three functions?

Comment: @mihaild OK, sure.